# Proof Maximum likelihood ratio test to be a $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

I have been struggling with this demonstration and I can not finish it, I want to demonstrate that for Gaussian samples (of $\sigma$ and $\mu$) the maximum likelihood ratio test holds for a $\chi^2$ distribution.

I want to prove it with a test statistic (z-test),

$$Z^2=\frac{n(\hat{x}-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2}$$

The likelihood ratio test is constructed as,

$$2\log LR=2\log \left( \frac{f(\theta_{ML})}{f(\theta_0)} \right)$$

With $\theta_{ML}$ the maximum likelihood parameter. I think I can find the function $f$ as the superposition of the Gaussian samples, i.e.,

$$f(?)=\frac{1}{(\sigma \sqrt{2\pi})^n}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum(x_i- \mu)}$$

And I don't know how to continue, and how can I use together the definition of the test $Z^2$ and the function $f$.

In summary, I want to demonstrate that with a Gaussian sample of independent measures($N(\mu,\sigma)$), the test statistic $Z^2$ distributes as a Cauchy distribution. And in order to demonstrate this I should use likelihood ratio test.

Comment: What is $H_0$ here? What is the alternative? Kindly specify them. Then coming to your query: are you on the quest to show LR follows chi square distribution, is it so? Perhaps a bit more clarity is warranted here.

Comment: Thanks, I added a final line clarifaying and summarizing all. I don't know at all what should be $H_0$... But I don't want to test some hypothesis. I want to prove that $Z^2$ test lead to a $\chi^2$ distribution, trough the use of LR

Comment: Does this reference help? Wilks: "The large-sample distribution of the likelihood ratio for testing composite hypotheses." The annals of mathematical statistics 9.1, pp. 60-62, 1938